# add drivers during installation of ORACLE linux 5.7

Tags: linux

How can I add driver for LSI 1068e raid when install oracle linux 5.7 ?because the install programe doesn't contain the proper driver for LSI 1068e,it can't see my local raid 1 managed by LSI 1068e.

Answer (score 1):

Use RHEL/CentOS 5.9 instead, which has device driver support for this card.

If for some reason you *can't* use 5.9...

You can [get the driver update disk directly from LSI](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS1068E.aspx). Look for LinuxMPT_SAS_RHEL5-6_SLES10-11_PH21-4.28.00.

This package is very large and includes source code and many binaries, among them will be a 1.44MB driver update disk image for RHEL 5 which [you can provide during installation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/chap-Updating_drivers_during_installation_on_Intel_and_AMD_systems.html).

Note that these drivers are only guaranteed to work on RHEL/CentOS, and may not work with Oracle Linux due to its using a different kernel.

Answer (score 0):

For x86-based systems, at the boot: prompt, enter **linux dd**. You will see something like [following](http://i.piccy.info/i7/c5133ef6d68fc33067849c3e2368b88a/4-66-412/34357047/linux_dd.png)